# Javadocs and multiline description?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I'm having trouble with javadocs. It seems to be both useful and extremely stupid!
I'm trying to write a multiline description for a class:

```
/**
 * this is my class, there are many like it, but this one is mine!
 * 
 * blah blah blah
 *       - blah blah
 *       - blah blah
*/
```

But when using that class the description is displayed as a single line blob!
Please tell me that the people who made it were smarter than this and that there is a way to make javadocs display multi-line description.

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Insert HTML tags, for example:

```
/**
 * <p>this is my class, there are many like it, but this one is mine!</p>
 * 
 * <p>blah blah blah<p>
 * <ul>
 *  <li>blah blah</li>
 *  <li>blah blah</li>
 * </ul>
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc works like a HTML. Just try something like

```
-blah blah <br /> -blah blah
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use html tags in the javadoc. For example, you can use the following:

```
/**
 * this is my class, there are many like it, but this one is mine!<br/>
 * 
 * blah blah blah
 *     <ul>  <li>blah blah</li>
 *       <li> blah blah</li>
 *     </ul>
*/
```